# Unable to find table class for current entity error in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

In my below code when I am getting complete zero result pr zero rows that time I am getting this error:

```
Unable to find table class for current entity error
```

And if any row is coming in the pagination that time everything is working fine.
Where I am doing wrong?

```
    $prProductFind=$this->PurchaseRequisitionProducts
    ->find()
    ->where([$condn,$conditions])
    ->matching('PurchaseOrderProducts', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
        return $q->where(['PurchaseOrderProducts.id IS NOT NULL']);
    })
    ->matching('PurchaseOrderProducts.PurchaseOrder', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
        return $q->where(['PurchaseOrder.id IS NOT NULL','PurchaseOrder.is_approve'=>"Y",'PurchaseOrder.po_type'=>1,'PurchaseOrder.status'=>1]);
    })

    ->group(['PurchaseRequisitionProducts.id'])
    ->order(["PurchaseRequisitionProducts.id"=>"desc"]);

       $pr_product = $this->paginate($prProductFind);
```

Comment: Have a look https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4698

Comment: @Sehdev any ways to do the fixes on controller ?

Comment: I tried to recreate this error on our website but could not. I didn't get any error.

Comment: @Sehdev is there any way to remove all the inner join if the result is empty or null?